# MVC5 DropdownlistFor The value '-1' is not valid for

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I have a strange situation. I am working with MVC5
I have client side validation enabled.

In my form i have a dropdownlistfor with a "please select..." as first item, The value of this item "please select..." is automatically set to value -1.

Now when i click the "Save" button on my form, without selecting any item in the dropdownlist, client side validation will not occur. The form will be submitted and then the Modelstate.Valid = false. The view will be showed again with an validation error on the dropdownlistfor saying: "The value '-1' is not valid for Owner".

1) I do not want the message to be "The value '-1' is not valid for owner". So can i somehow adjust this message?
2) How can i make sure that clientside validation occeurs and prevents a postback

When i select the first option "Please select..." in the drodownlist and click somewhere else in the screen, clientside validation does work. I see my error message, but i can still click the save button and submit the form.

Does anyone have any clue?
I cannot find anything like this on the internet

I have a Viewmodel with the following properties:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Owner is required.")]
// Any guid but not an empty guid. 
[RegularExpression(@"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$", ErrorMessage = "Owner is required.")]
public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }

public SelectList Owners { get; set; }
```

In my Razor i have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OwnerId, Model.Owners, "Select a value...", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwnerId)
```

Comment: The value of the label option is not set to `-1`. Its set to `null` - it generates `<option value="">Select a value...</option>`

Comment: And as a side note, your `[RegularExpression]` attribute is not necessary

Comment: In my case the value of <option value="">Select a value...</option> is set to -1.

Comment: Impossible unless you have written some other code that sets it

Comment: I did not write any other code than described above. 
I have no editor or display template for dropdowns. Just pure and plain mvc

Comment: What you are claiming is simply not possible unless you have written code to override the default behavior. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrxmFT). Leave the default option and click the submit button - note the standard error. Then select an option and click the submit button

Comment: I understand what you say and ofcourse i have tested the standard behavior in a sample project. As i told you before, i did not write any C# code or JS code to adjust the default behavior. I will take a look if a JS library maybe adjust it without my knowledge.

Comment: I found the solution. Material Design library adjusted the selects so thanks for pointing to this direction. Is solved

Answer (score 0):

Material design script was adjusting the selects. Thanks Stephen for pointing to this direction